# How can I update same label with different values?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *
import fnd
from fnd import fake_news
import infer
def find_news():
    global e
    string = e.get()
    ans=infer.fake_fake(string)
    if(ans==0):
        w = Label(window, text="FAKE",bg="red",fg="white",font="none 19 bold")
        w.pack()
    else:
        w= Label(window,text="REAL",bg="green",fg="white",font="none 19 bold")
        w.pack()



window = Tk()

window.title('AVIS')
window.geometry("500x500")

window.configure(background='black')
l1=Label(window,text="",bg="black",fg="white",font="none 19 bold")
l1.pack()
l1.focus_set()

l=Label(window,text="Enter headline of news:",bg="black",fg="white",font="none 12 bold")
l.pack()
l.focus_set()

e = Entry(window,width=200)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()



b = Button(window,text='submit',command=find_news)
b.pack(side='bottom')
window.mainloop()
```

I am getting a answer from a function and according to it i have to set whether it  is fake or not in the label. How can I different values to the same label. [If is fake it comes FAKE one below another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvGg8.png)

Comment: Please give your full code

Comment: `w.config(text="anything")`

Comment: There must be a thousand questions and answers on this site about updating labels. Did you do any research or read any documentation before asking?

Comment: w.config(text="anything") dosent work. Still it is coming one below the other

Comment: Yes i did but didnt work

Comment: @SandeepChavan it does work and is correct. The point is its well documented and the simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create the label in your main code and then update the label with `config()`. That said I don't think you did much research as this is one of the fundamental basics of tkinter and there are already hundreds of questions on this matter or more.

```
from tkinter import *

def find_news():
    global e
    string = e.get()
    ans=infer.fake_fake(string)
    if(ans==0):
        w.config(text="FAKE", bg="red", fg="white", font="none 19 bold")
    else:
        w.config(text="REAL", bg="green", fg="white", font="none 19 bold")


window = Tk()

window.title('AVIS')
window.geometry("500x500")
window.configure(background='black')

l1 = Label(window, text="", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 19 bold")
l1.pack()

l = Label(window, text="Enter headline of news:", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold")
l.pack()

e = Entry(window,width=200)
e.pack()

w = Label(window, bg="black")
w.pack()

b = Button(window, text='submit', command=find_news)
b.pack(side='bottom')
window.mainloop()
```